# Get the center TextView of a PieChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I am struggling with getting the `View` object that represents the `TextView` inside the `PieChart` ("Blabla" in the following example image):

[image: Example PieChart]

I need the `View` object because I need to pass it to a `Showcase` [library](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) in order to make a showcase around that `TextView`. The library needs to get the position and size of the object it has to draw a showcase around.

The only thing I have is the `PieChart` object. And from that I need to get the `TextView` object that represents the center text.

Do you have any guess on how I can do this?

Comment: You can easily clear the `PieChart` center text, and put the `PieChart` in a `FrameLayout` containing a `TextView` with `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: :/ I don't like this solution very much because I'll have to manage the size of the TextView so it doesn't go outside the center of the chart etc. It looks like a bug source to me, whereas I get the center TextView out of the box with the PieChart directly.

Comment: here is the source code for `PieChartRenderer`: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/PieChartRenderer.java
it seems it doesn't use any `TextView` at all as it draw the text itself